# What is the history for naming constants in all uppercase?

Tags: c, history, naming-standards

What is the history behind the convention of naming constants in all uppercase?

My intuition is that it started with the C preprocessor, where people developed a practice to name preprocessor macros in all uppercase so that they would effectively live in a separate namespace and avoid name collisions.  My belief is that this practice was then misunderstood and bastardized to apply to non-preprocessor constants too (`enum`s, `const` variables).

Naming preprocessor macros in all uppercase seems genuinely useful to me.  Naming general constants that way, not so much (and counterproductive if it creates collisions with macro names).

Am I off base?  Did the practice of capitalizing constants predate C?

Comment: I think you are right here. Early languages had pretty much everything in upper case, with the use of lower case becoming fashionable later. Early C books seem to typically show `const` identifiers being lower case and `#defines` as upper. Java though adopted upper case for constants and other languages followed, but I could have that last bit wrong. More research needed! :)

Comment: I concur with @DavidArno probably because of the nature of either C or assembler.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For C, the first edition of *The C Programming Language* (a.k.a. K&R) suggests that your intuition about preprocessor macros is correct:

> Symbolic constant names are commonly written in upper case so they can be readily distinguished from lower case
>   variable names.

In many ways, this was a holdover from assembly language, where macros were defined in uppercase along with labels, opcodes, register names and everything else.  The advent of AT&T-style assembly changed that on some platforms, but I think it was heavily influenced by the fact that terminals supporting lowercase were becoming a thing and Unix was what I'd call a "lowercase operating system."

On the other two points, you're batting .500:

## Enum

By the time the second edition was published, `enum`s had been defined, they were referred to as *enumeration constants* and covered in the section on constants.  Because the constants defined by an `enum` are represented by symbols, that makes them symbolic constants, which, if you're going to follow the recommended convention, should be named in uppercase.  (Like preprocessor macros, nothing stops you from doing otherwise.)

The implication here is that unlike some languages that followed, C does not treat `enum` as a first class type where the types themselves are distinct, enumeration values are specific to each type and may be re-used in others.  Instead, it's effectively a convenient shorthand for `#define` that produces sequences of integers with identifiers attached.  This makes

```
enum foo  { BAR, BAZ };
enum quux { BLETCH, BAZ };
```

invalid because all of the symbols share scope and `BAZ` is redefined.  (This was an improvement over the preprocessor which, at the time, didn't warn about one `#define` clobbering another.)  Further, C doesn't care whether you mix them because they're all just integers, making

```
enum foo  { BAR, BAZ };
enum quux { BLETCH, BLRFL };

enum foo variable = BLETCH;
```

completely valid even on a modern compiler with all of the warnings turned on.

## Const

NB:  The `const` keyword originated in 1981 with Stroustrup's C With Classes (which evolved into C++) and was eventually adopted by C.  The choice of name is unfortunate, because it collides with K&R's use of the term *constant* to mean what we would now call a *literal* (e.g., `38`, `'x'` or `"squabble"`).  The text in the second edition wasn't rewritten to reflect that.

Variables declared `const` are a different story because they're still variables.  They're not supposed to be modified, but whether the notion of a constant variable makes any more sense than, say, jumbo shrimp is fodder for another discussion.  Whatever the case, C was never really serious about it because the standard only requires that the compiler emit a diagnostic when you attempt to change one.  The actual behavior is undefined if a modification is compiled and executed.

Being variables, it makes sense that anything `const` would follow the convention of being named in lowercase.  Using them to represent literals does have some type safety advantages but doesn't make for good optimization if you have to reach between compilation units to get the value.

What they aren't is constants in the K&R sense, and for that reason their identifiers shouldn't be uppercase.  Some people use them that way, but it isn't a practice I recommend except in a few specific cases.

Comment: I'm going to accept this, and while I appreciate the answer, the `enum` paragraphs about not being first-class types and about redefinition conflicts don't seem relevant.  That the first edition of K&R described the practice being for "symbolic constants" is enough. (Also, after checking my copy of the second edition of K&R, I see that their examples all name `enum` constants in all uppercase, so that further validates your answer.)